# Using JQuery onblur to set textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, onblur

I have a textbox with these rules:
1) I populate the textbox.text from a dictionary in session
2) If the user enters a new value, setTextBoxData will save it in the dictionary
3) On entry (on focus) the field text is blanked.
4) On blur, if the field is still empty, I want to set it to the original value.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberEmployees" runat="server" Width="50px" onfocus="this.value='';"  
onchange= "javaScript:$(function()setTextBoxData('NUMBEREMPLOYEES','txtNumberEmployees');});"
onblur="javaScript:restore ('txtNumberEmployees', 'NUMBEREMPLOYEES');"/>
```

The "restore" function referenced above is:

```
function restore(control, input) {
    var data = getInputData(input);
    $('#' + control).val(data);
}
```

getInputData returns the data value correctly. The problem is with the last line.

I have tried many ways to set this, but none seem to work. It should be a simple problem, but I can't get it to work yet.

Comment: looks like a syntax error:
`javaScript:$(function()setTextBoxData('NUMBEREMPLOYEES','txtNumberEmployees');});`

shouldn't it just be
`javaScript:setTextBoxData('NUMBEREMPLOYEES','txtNumberEmployees');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is ASP.NET will generate an ID that will not be `txtNumberEmployees`. ASP.NET will generate an ID for your input that will end with `txtNumEmployees`.

Change this line:

```
$('#' + control).val(data);
```

to this:

```
$('[id$=' + control + ']').val(data);
```

It will work because this is the [Attribute Ends with Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Comment: Thanks. I think of programming as a form of sorcery. If we don't utter the right spell, the brooms will pick up the buckets and playing mischievously. If you don't understand the reference, watch "Fantasia".

Comment: When it comes to Javascript and jQuery, your comparison is totally valid. And I kinda like it :-)

Answer (score 1):

1: Make sure you have no javascript errors. I see there's a missing '{' in the onchange.

2: You can simply pass 'this' as the textbox reference and update it like below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberEmployees" runat="server" Width="50px" onfocus="this.value='';"  
onchange= "javaScript:$(function(){setTextBoxData('NUMBEREMPLOYEES',this);});"
onblur="javaScript:restore (this, 'NUMBEREMPLOYEES');"/>
```

then simply set the value like:

```
$(control).val(data);
```

3: There are other ways as well to grab an asp.net element like shown here. [Find ASP.NET ClientID in jquery](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jQuery)